# Notification badge on floating action button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to add the items to the cart. The cart will be Floating action button and item count I want to show on top of it. Please help me with this.

[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ble3r.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case, you don't want to install any 3rd party package, you can always use the `Stack` widget to create your own badge.

Basically, while setting the `floatingActionButton` property of you `Scaffold`, you can use a `Stack` widget to build your `Badge`.

For example:

```
class BadgeExample extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(),
    floatingActionButton: Container(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment(1.4, -1.5),
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(  // Your actual Fab
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            ),
            Container(             // This is your Badge
              child: Center(
                  // Here you can put whatever content you want inside your Badge
                  child: Text('4', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32, minWidth: 32),
              decoration: BoxDecoration( // This controls the shadow
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 5,
                    color: Colors.black.withAlpha(50))
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.blue,  // This would be color of the Badge
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the floatingActionButton receive Widget type, this mean that you can make Widget a FloactionActionButton, so, you can use badges package, like this:

```
Badge(
        toAnimate: true,
        shape: BadgeShape.circle,
        badgeColor: Colors.red,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        badgeContent: Text('0', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.shopping_cart,
        ),
      )
```

Link to the package: https://pub.dev/packages/badges